# '?' being appened in the retrieved command line arguments send via mvn exec:java

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have the below command to invoke a maven project.

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="utility.DriverScript" -Dexec.classpathScope=test -Dexec.args=”’D:\ABC\ExcelDriver.xlsx’”
```

When I receive the args in Main methods, I get the value as

```
??D:\ABC\ExcelDriver.xlsx??
```

I even tried the below type while sending args but no luck

```
-Dexec.args=”’D:\\ABC\\ExcelDriver.xlsx’”
-Dexec.args=”’D:/ABC/ExcelDriver.xlsx’”
```

When I tried with `-Dexec.args=”D:\ABC\ExcelDriver.xlsx”`, I got the output as ?

```
D:\ABC\ExcelDriver.xlsx?
```

What am I doing wrong here. Any pointer would help. Maven Version 3.3.9

My POM build looks like,

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

one more weird stuff. I decided to put a hack fix for the same. But replace function doesn't seem to work at all.

```
System.out.println(args[0].toString());  //Prints "??args[0]value??" 
String s = args[0].toString();
String firstword = s.replace("?", "");
System.out.println(firstword);  //Prints "??args[0]value??"
```

Comment: Looks like the char arround the Parameter is not a double quote

Comment: what does your pom look like? Could you share the build part of it at least.

Comment: one more weird stuff. I decided to put a hack fix for the same. But replace function doesn't seem to work at all.                             System.out.println(args[0].toString());  //Prints "??args[0]value??"
  String s = args[0].toString();
  String firstword = s.replace("?", "");
  System.out.println(firstword); // Prints "??args[0]value??"

Answer (score 0):

As i commented, the char arroung -Dexec.args... are not double quotes. So Change to:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="utility.DriverScript" -Dexec.classpathScope=test -Dexec.args="D:\ABC\ExcelDriver.xlsx"
```

The signs you have are not printable signs,so it will be showed as question mark

Comment: When I tried the above, I got the output as ?D:\ABC\ExcelDriver.xlsx?. In the question, I have intentionally put a single quote inside a double quote so that even if there are any spaces within them, that would be taken as a single argument. I not sure the issue is with maven ? I even tried a simple input like -Dexec.args="Name", I get the output as ?Name?